# I would extract values from 2 tables in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables. The first has the following columns:

- tax_id
- exp_date

and the second table has

- fiscal_code

I would take all the `tax_id` from the first column which are different from `fiscal_code`, but I would also print the query result with the `exp_date`.

I expect this result:

| tax_id | exp_date |
| --- | --- |
| bb | 20-11-23 |
| cc | 20-11-23 |
| dd | 20-11-23 |

How can I do to print also `exp_date`?

Comment: Check out `NOT IN`, or `NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: Next time, please show some sample data. You are showing a result, but what is the data leading to this result? And "tax_id that are different from fiscal_code" is not really clear. Which tax_id is different from which fiscal_code? You probably want to say "tax_ids that cannot be found as a fiscal_code in the other table" or "tax_ids that don't exist as a fiscal_code in the other table". Once you get the wording right, you are more likely to find the SQL keyword you need (`EXISTS` in this case).

Answer (score 1):

The most basic way, do `NOT IN` subquery.

```
select tax_id, exp_date
from table1
where tax_id not in (select fiscal_code from table2)
```

Comment: Ok, but if I make the standard query like : SELECT distinct tax_id from table 1 where tax_id not in (select fiscal_code from table2) it gives me 1800 records. But, if i make the query : SELECT distinct tax_id, exp_date from table 1 where tax_id not in (select fiscal_code from table2) it gives me 2500 records instead 1800, why?

Comment: `select distinct tax_id` will return each tax_id only once. `select distinct tax_id, exp_date` will return a tax_id multiple times if it's having different exp_date's. `select distinct` is used to return distinct _rows_.

Comment: Ok and so how can I obtain 1800 instead 2500 records with tax_id and exp_date? Because I want a query results with this two columns without duplicate (I would print only 1800 records)

Comment: @Mariomaxi: `SELECT DISTINCT` is something rarely needed. If you are about to use it, ask yourself what forces you to make rows distinct. Where do the duplicates that you want to remove stem from? In this case you seem to be mistaken in what `SELECT DISTINCT` actually does, as jarlh correctly explained.

Comment: @Mariomaxi:: There are no duplicates in the result. If you want unique tax_ids, then what exp_date would you show for a tax_ids? The oldest? The newest? Some average? ... You seem to be looking for some aggregation (`MIN`, `MAX`, ...) per tax_id.

Answer (score 0):

Use `left join`

```
select t1.tax_id,exp_date
from table1 t1 left join t2 on t1.tax_id=t2.fiscal_code
where t2.fiscal_code is null
```

Comment: Why? As this is not as straight-forward as `NOT IN` and `NOT EXISTS`, you should explain how such an anti join works and why you prefer it here over the more straight-forward methods.